# What is the precision of Amazon FPS monetary amounts?

Tags: currency, amazon-fps

My application needs to track payments made with FPS precisely. It's not clear to me from the documentation what the possible precisions of monetary values in the FPS system are.

For instance,

[image: Amazon Payments Account Activity]

In this screenshot from my sandbox account, my Amazon account balance is $809.848, and one of the fees is -$0.619.

Is $0.001 the smallest amount I should be tracking, or do Amazon FPS amounts get smaller?

Comment: That sounds like a question for FPS support. Let us know what you find :) https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/contactussend

Comment: Good idea. :) I've sent an email; I'll report back.